# How to set root password in MariaDB 10.4 on macOS?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have just installed MariaDB 10.4 on macOS Mojave and I now need to set a password for the `root` user. I read on other SO questions that I can achieve this via

```
sudo mysql -u root
MariaDB [mysql]> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSOWRD('mypassword') WHERE user = 'root';
```

but this raises error

`ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable`

and if I try

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('mypassword') WHERE User='root';
```

raises error

`ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'Password' is not updatable`

This

`set password for 'root'@'localhost' = 'mypassword';`

throws

`ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number`

and this

`alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'mypassword';`

throws

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version...`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why we lead to this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since MariaDB 10.4 `mysql.global_priv` has replaced `mysql.user`. Latter one is now a view, which can't be updated anymore.

Since you already logged in as root, keep it simple and change your password with:

```
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('mypassword')
```

Since the user can't be authenticated over socket anymore, the authentication method will be automatically set to mysql_native_password.

Comment: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 8):

For 10.4, I had to run this command to force the password prompt for the root user:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password 
USING PASSWORD('my secret password');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Looks like the install process has changed to using unix_socket authentication plugin by default
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/

Answer (score 5):

If update command give error like `column 'password' is not updatable`
then use alter command instead.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

then

```
flush privileges;
```

then update this password in config.inc.php file so that you can access http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: I had to first run ```flush privileges```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something here - sometimes you must run `flush privileges;` before you try to set the password.
so the command will be:

```
flush privileges;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD("some_password");
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the mysql user:

```
SET password for 'mysql'@'localhost' = password('mypassword');
```